# Iteration of calendar.month_name can't be parsed by strptime()

Tags: python, for-loop, strptime

Here's something that seems a little silly: `datetime.strptime()` is happy to accept an iterated list of month names when I just create a list by hand (`months = ['January','February']`) but not when I iterate over a list of months created by `calendar.month_name` even though both return `<type 'str'>`

Broken code:

```
import datetime
import calendar
for month in calendar.month_name:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(month,"%B")
```

Error:
`ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%B'`

Working code:

```
import datetime
months = ['January','February','March']
for month in months:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(month,"%B")
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00
1900-02-01 00:00:00
1900-03-01 00:00:00
```

What's going on here? Is this a behavior of python's `for` loop I am not familiar with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing `print( list(calendar.month_name) )` and it will become obvious pretty quickly why this fails ... (mainly because the first element yielded is an empty string).  Note that the reason the first month yielded is an empty string is because they want `month_names[1]` to correspond to `January` as is the common convention (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html?highlight=calendar#calendar.month_name))

You *could* do something like this:

```
a = list( calendar.month_names )[1:]
```

or this also works in Cpython at least (although it isn't clear in the documentation if it should):

```
a = calendar.month_names[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It looks like starting the loop with the index of 1 (`for month in calendar.month_name[1:]:`) also works. That's great!

Comment: @wire42 -- Yeah, I realized that too (after some experimenting).  The documentation uses the term `array` which is a little ambiguous as to the return type.  But it seems to be sliceable (at least in Cpython)

Answer (score 1):

As [noted by mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675586/5987) the first item returned is an empty string. It's trivial to ignore it:

```
for month in calendar.month_name:
    if month:
        print datetime.datetime.strptime(month,"%B")
```

Or to use a list comprehension to remove it:

```
for month in [month_name for month_name in calendar.month_name if month_name]:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(month,"%B")
```

Comment: The powerful simplicity of Python's `if`(and `for`) statements make me happy and nervous at the same time. It reads like it's saying "Well, if it's a month" but of course `if` has no idea if it's a month or not. It just returns false on empty string. It's a pretty elegant solution, though. Do you think it's more robust than the slice-based solution?

Comment: @wire42, it depends on what you mean by "robust". It certainly handles the case where a new blank string is added to the list somewhere, or removed - but that isn't likely to happen. Using a slice notation probably better expresses the fact that it's a 1-based array.